# How to access a PDKPin's Image/largest Image properties in Pinterest SDK for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

I realize this is a newer API, so I'm adding the pertinent source code from the SDK.  The problem I'm having is its written in Obj-C, which I don't know so trying to figure out what the SDK/Example app are doing is difficult.  Per the documentation https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk there is an `.image` and `.largestImage` property available.  In Xcode, `PDKPin.image` and `PDKPin.largestImage` will compile but they return nil.

In the example app they successfully call `.image` on a `PDKPin`, so I can't figure out what they're doing that I am not:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.pins count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PDKPin *pin = self.pins[indexPath.row];
    PDKPinCell *cell = (PDKPinCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PinCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = pin.descriptionText;


    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:pin.largestImage.url];

    return cell;
}
```

It looks like the .image property may be on PDKImageInfo:

```
#import "PDKImageInfo.h"

@interface PDKImageInfo()

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat width;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat height;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSURL *url;
@end

    @implementation PDKImageInfo

    + (instancetype)imageFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
    {
        PDKImageInfo *image = [[PDKImageInfo alloc] init];
        image.width = [dictionary[@"width"] floatValue];
        image.height = [dictionary[@"height"] floatValue];
        if ([dictionary[@"url"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            image.url = [NSURL URLWithString:dictionary[@"url"]];
        }
        return image;
    }

    @end
```

But I can't figure out how to access it from a PDKPin as they did in the example app.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I simply forgot that `getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields` takes a dictionary and I failed to add the `image` key

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields(Set(["url", "note", "link", "image"])
```